# Не переводятся названия встроенных действий “Mail to Self” и “Save to Files” на экране “Поделиться”

Tags: swift

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему могут не переводиться на русский язык названия встроенных действий “Mail to Self” и “Save to Files” на экране “Поделиться”?
Язык на устройстве русский, кнопки “Скопировать” и “Редактировать действия” перевелись.
В info.plist добавлено Localized resources can be mixed = YES (без этого не переводились кнопки “Скопировать” и “Редактировать действия”), но для “Mail to Self” и “Save to Files” это не работает.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С помощью [Claude31] в [тикете](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/667963?login=true&page=1#649866022)  решение было найдено.
В info.plist "Localization native development region" было `"$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)"`.
После установки "ru" все было переведено.